# Checking some work on an expectation value problem

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, quantum-mechanics

I am working on a pretty simple problem (or so it seems it should be) from Griffith's QM text.

The problem states: for the probability density function $\rho (x) = Ae^{-\lambda(x-a)^2}$

a) find A
b) find $\langle x \rangle$, $\langle x^2 \rangle$ and $\sigma$

I set up the integral and got a result for A, (I did a substitution and then a change of variables to polar coordinates) and since $1 = \int^{+\infty}_{+\infty}\rho(x)\,dx$ I ended up with $A=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}}$. So far so good.

Then I set up the integral with that value for A. In this case
$$\langle x \rangle = \int^{+\infty}_{+\infty}x\rho(x)\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\lambda}{\pi}} \int^{+\infty}_{+\infty}xe^{-\lambda(x-a)^2}\,dx$$
again so far so good. Now, what I wanted to know was whether the following was permissible. I think so, but I can't shake the feeling that I am doing something wrong.

Now to be clear, I could integrate by parts as it is. But in that case I started getting repeating intgrals (I used $u=e^{-\lambda(x-a)^2}\,dx$, $du = -2\lambda e^{-\lambda(x-a)^2}\,dx$ and $dv=x\,dx$ and $v=\frac{x^2}{2}$.

SO I tried something else. I did another substitution first. I said, let $u=x-a$. That means $x=u+a$ and $dx=du$. That gets me the following: 
$$\int^{+\infty}_{+\infty}(u+a)e^{-\lambda(u)^2}du=\int^{+\infty}_{+\infty}ue^{-\lambda(u)^2}du+\int^{+\infty}_{+\infty}ae^{-\lambda(u)^2}du$$

which is a LOT easier to do. From there I get 
$$\left[\frac{e^{-\lambda u^2}}{-2\lambda}\right]^{+\infty}_{-\infty}+a\int^{+\infty}_{+\infty}e^{-\lambda u^2}du$$
Now, the second term is a famous integral- it's the same one that if I do yet anothr substitution to turn it into polar coordinates I would get $a\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}$ and that means: $$\langle x \rangle = a\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\lambda}}$$ because the first term has to go to zero.

So, I am basically just asking if this was the correct thing to do. I can't see anything mathematically wrong but I like to make sure I didn't delude myself somewhere.

Comment: It is fine, the right thing to do. (I have not checked your constants.)  I would be tempted to let $\lambda=\frac{2}{\sigma^2}$ and quote facts about the normal.

Comment: We are assuming $\lambda$, $a$ and $A$ are all >0 and Real, btw. And thanks! It seemed too simple to do but I feel like I am finally getting a handle on this, after two years of struggle.(so, yay!)

Comment: We don't care about the sign of $a$. But for convergence we need $\lambda\gt 0$.

Comment: I assume your initial mention of $\lambda = \frac{2}{a^2}$ applies only if $\lambda < 0$? Or is it more general? (If there's a cool technique I don't know I am all ears).

Comment: It was a mistake, I meant $\lambda=\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}$. Then one can quote the standard fact that $\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}$ is the density function of the normal mean $\mu$, variance $\sigma^2$.